# How to get and post 2 objects from ng-model?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

**I have here a sample document from mongodb named chapters:**

`{_id:5c014c999cc48c3b0057988b, chapter_name:"AB"}`

**Controller:** here is my function to get the chapters, and function to post to another db:

```
.controller('regCtrl', function($http, $location, $timeout, User, Bloodbankchapter) {
    Bloodbankchapter.getBloodbankchapters().then(function(data) {        
        app.bloodbankchapters = data.data.bloodbankchapters;                 
    });

this.regUser = function(regData) {
    User.create(app.regData).then(function(data) {});
};
```

**Then in my front-end to register:**

```
 <form name="regForm" ng-submit="register.regUser(regData); ">
    <label>Chapter Name</label> <!--After I select the chapter name -->
    <select ng-model="register.regData.branch" ng-options ="chapter._id as chapter.chapter_name for chapter in register.bloodbankchapters">
    <option ng-repeat="chapter in register.bloodbankchapters" >{{chapter.chapter_name}}</option>
    </select>
    
    <label>Chapter ID</label> <!--chapter ID will appear here-->
    <input type="text" ng-model="register.regData.branch_id" hidden>

    <label>Chapter name</label> <!--How to make chapter name appear here?-->
    <input type="text" ng-model="register.regData.branch_name" hidden>
    <button ng-disabled="register.disabled" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My problem here is after I selected the chapter name the second input was correct and it post the id into the db, but how can I get the chapter.name and post it to db?

I tried getting the text value from the select box and then appending it to a textbox like here: http://jsfiddle.net/kxqJN/, but when I register, the object id is being registered instead of chapter_name like this:

```
`{branch_id:5c014c999cc48c3b0057988b, branch_name:"5c014c999cc48c3b0057988b"}`
```

**How can I display the name in the first box and the id in the second?**

[image]

Comment: You seem to be using the `_id` for your options `chapter_name` values here: `chapter._id as chapter.chapter_name`. What does it look like if you replace it by `chapter.chapter_name for chapter in register.bloodbankchapters track by chapter._id`?

Comment: when I used chapter.chapter_name it shows the chapter_name, but I need to register both the id and the chapter_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you haven't tried what i suggested in the comments: `chapter.chapter_name for chapter in register.bloodbankchapters track by chapter._id` will lead you to have both values in your model:

```js
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.register = {
      regData: {
        branch: {},
      },
      bloodbankchapters: [
        {_id:'5c014c999cc48c3b0057988b', chapter_name:"AB"},
        {_id:'5c014c999cc48c3b0057988c', chapter_name:"A"},
      ],
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="selectExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <select ng-model="register.regData.branch" ng-options ="chapter.chapter_name for chapter in register.bloodbankchapters track by chapter._id">
    <option ng-repeat="chapter in register.bloodbankchapters" >{{chapter.chapter_name}}</option>
  </select>
  <div>{{register.regData.branch}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: now  its showing, but this shows the whole document: here is what I get{_id":"5c014c999cc48c3b0057988b","chapter_name":"Caloocan","chapter_address":"7th Ave. Grace Park, Caloocan City","chapter_email":"caloocan@redcross.org.ph","chapter_category":"Blood Collecting Unit/Blood Station","chapter_id":"111"}

Comment: is it possible to output only a certain field like chapter.chapter_id and chapter.chapter_name

Comment: you're welcome! You can still use a pipe to modify objects in the `ng-repeat` (i think) and keep only what you want, but i'm no specialist of angular pipes. As a workaroud, i would use a function to get just what you want, something like ` in getBloodbankchapters()`, but that's because i'm no specialist :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, you will get selected chapter object inside **register.regData.branch**

```
<select ng-model="register.regData.branch" ng-options ="chapter as chapter.value for chapter in register.bloodbankchapters">
```

Comment: does not work i need to display the id in the second textbox

Comment: to display branch_name and branch_id i think you need to use     `ng-model="register.regData.branch.branch_id" ` and `ng-model="register.regData.branch.branch_name"`

Comment: it is possible to bind this in one input?